# Visual Studio 2015: Invalid "Cast is redundant" warning in interpolated string expression

Tags: c#, casting, visual-studio-2015, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Consider this simple program which compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015:

```
public class Program
{
    enum Direction
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Old style
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The direction is {0}", Direction.Right));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The direction is {0}", (int)Direction.Right));

        // New style
        Console.WriteLine($"The direction is {Direction.Right}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The direction is {(int)Direction.Right}");
    }
}
```

... which outputs as expected:

```
The direction is Right
The direction is 3
The direction is Right
The direction is 3
```

However, Visual Studio 2015 keeps suggesting a "Quick Action" on this line specifically:

```
// "Cast is redundant" warning
Console.WriteLine($"The direction is {(int)Direction.Right}");
```

It insists that the `(int)` *"cast is redundant"*, and suggests as a potential fix to *"Remove Unnecessary Cast"*, which of course is wrong, as it would change the result.

Interestingly, it doesn't give me any warning for the equivalent statement:

```
// No warnings.
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The direction is {0}", (int)Direction.Right));
```

Can someone provide a reasonable explanation for this false-positive when using an expression in an interpolated string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4037).

A temporary fix has been proposed for the mean time:

> For people experiencing this bug in VS2015 now, a workaround is to suppress warning IDE0004 in the build tab of the property pages of the affected project.

This has been fixed and merged into master on 09/09/2015 in [PR 5029](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5029/files).

Answer (score 3):

The explicit cast *is* unnecessary in a way - you can (and probably should) use a format specifier:

```
$"The direction is {Direction.Right:d}"
```

But yeah, the warning is silly - it should suggest this change, not just removing `(int)`. The compiler has quite a few kinks - fortunately, most seem to be very easy to work around.

Comment: Didn't know you could use the `d` format specifier on an enum without casting first. Thanks for the workaround.  Of course, I didn't mention this in my question, but in my real world problem, my string looks more like this `$"The direction is {(int)Direction.Right:X8}"`. So I really do need the cast, otherwise I get a `FormatException`.  But this is useful, thank you!